Как сделать ожидание в AppScript?
Как сделать ожидание, пока в нужной ячейке гугл таблицы не появится значение, затем продолжить выполнение скрипта?
Или просто как дождаться вставки всех значений на лист, потом продолжать скрипт?

Никак. Это неправильное понимание облачных вычислений. Запускайте скрипт дважды или трижды.

Этот вариант я проверил  первым делом и он не работает. И да, это плохой паттерн.

Почитайте про .flush() вот тут.
Скорее всего вам надо дождаться, пока выполнятся все вычисления на листе.

Спасибо, попробую.

Используйте if для проверки значения в нужной ячейке и sleep(milliseconds) для паузы. Значение milliseconds указывается в миллисекундах.
Ссылка на документацию: https://developers-google-com.translate.goog/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=sc#sleep(Integer)

Спасибо за подсказку, но проблему это не  решило. Есть такой скрипт:

@Михаил не прикрепили скрипт

С первого раза  не получилось :)
ss.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(9, 1);
ss.getRange('A9').setValue(new Date());
ss.getRange('B9').setValue(ss.getRange('B3').getValue())
ss.getRange('C9').setValue(ss.getRange('C3').getValue())
ss.getRange('D9').setValue(ss.getRange('D3').getValue())
ss.getRange('E9').setValue(ss.getRange('E3').getValue())

ss.getRange('D3').clearContent();

Utilities.sleep(3000);
summary()

В ячейках появляются значения, потом  зависает на  Е9 и считает сумму без нее. Sleep добавляет паузу перед  вставкой последней ячейки.

Лист гугл таблицы не обновляется, пока не закончится sleep  и скрипт summary считает пустую ячейку.

Может есть команда вставки массива сразу  во все ячейки,  по аналогии с Excel VBA?

@Михаил не совсем понятна задача и код не полный. Можете поделиться ссылкой на таблицу и описать конкретную задачу?

Так не надо делать. Это плохой паттерн.

@Марина  Задача скопировать  значения из 3-й строки в  9-ю, затем  просуммировать полученную таблицу (с 9-й строки и ниже) по нескольким  критериям. Перед вставкой последней ячейки Е3-Е9 лист "подвисает" и дальнейший скрипт обрабатывает значения  с пустой Е9. Добавление  sleep не  помогло, лист так же "зависает" на время  sleep. Решил проблему "костылем" - вставкой пустой ячейки F3-F9, лист теперь "подвисает  перед ней, но в дальнейший расчет попадают заполненные  А9-Е9, как  и задумано.

@Марина Делал тестовый вариант (который и помог  разобраться в проблеме), скрипт  summary это простое суммирование  и  вся таблица маленькая, там  вставка работает как и задумано, без костылей.

@oshliaer плохой  паттерн  использовать sleep или копировать значения  из  одних ячеек в другие?

@Михаил почему бы просто не использовать вставку целой строки? getRange позволяет получать массив значений. Иными словами, если в троке у вас стоит 100 чисел, то getRange может взять всю строку а функция getVlues() позволит вам получить все значения из строки
